# Debugging inside Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I wanted to debug / print the values inside the code block

```
Rails.cache.fetch(some values) do
 #want to get the values from this blocks.

end
```

Tried with Rails.logger.ap, puts, debugger. Nothing worked out. I am assuming is it just due to the cache fetch?

Please suggest me some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete the cache content, the block will be invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expound on what apneadiving commented.

Since you are using cache, Rails will only run the block only once until you delete the content.  See what happens in the following code

```
>> Rails.cache.fetch(:foo) { 'bar' } # writes 'foo' to cache with value 'bar' since this is the first time you run the command
>> Rails.cache.fetch(:foo) { 'bar' } # fetches 'foo' from cache since it's already in the cache so the block is not executed
```

if you want to debug what's inside of the block, you can remove the call to cache first (evaluate the block always) or add `Rails.cache.delete(:foo)` before the block.